# Why is nothing happening when I try to run this JS code inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, react-native

I have a file named `test.php` which has this whole code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Payment Receipt</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
...
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if($row) {
    $obj->txndate = $row['date'];
    $obj->txnid = $row['txnid'];
    $obj->atomid = $row['atomid'];
    $obj->amount = $row['amount'];
    
    $myJSON = json_encode($obj);
    echo $myJSON;

    //javascript starts inside PHP

    echo '<script>', PHP_EOL;
    echo 'var msg = <?php echo json_encode($myJSON); ?>;', PHP_EOL;
    echo 'var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {', PHP_EOL;
    echo 'postMessage: function (message) {', PHP_EOL;
    echo 'if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {', PHP_EOL;
    echo 'window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);', PHP_EOL;
    echo '} else {', PHP_EOL;
    echo 'window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');', PHP_EOL;
    echo '}', PHP_EOL;
    echo '}', PHP_EOL;
    echo '}', PHP_EOL;
    echo 'ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);', PHP_EOL;
    echo '</script>', PHP_EOL;
    
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect ID';
}

$conn->close();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, nothing happens in the JavaScript side - everything works well until the JavaScript starts. This is the JavaScript code I tried to embed in the PHP code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myJSON = 'Hi there!';
?>

<script>
var msg = <?php echo json_encode($myJSON); ?>;
var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
    postMessage: function (message) {
        if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);
        } else {
            window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
        }
    }
}

ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code works well as expected when I run it separately in a different file, which too has the PHP variable passed in the `var msg` command.

I wonder what I did wrong trying to write JavaScript code inside PHP - I saw somewhere that by echoing the statement, then adding `PHP_EOL` at the end we can write JS/HTML in-between PHP.

What's wrong here? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This does not work:

```
echo '<script>', PHP_EOL;
echo 'var msg = <?php echo json_encode($myJSON); ?>;', PHP_EOL;
```

because it sends PHP code *to the client*, which will not execute it since it has no PHP parser.

Write it like this:

```
$jsonEncoded = json_encode($myJSON);

echo <<<JS001
<script>
var msg = {$jsonEncoded};
var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
    postMessage: function (message) {
        if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);
        } else {
            window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');'
        }
    }
};
ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);
</script>
JS001;
// The line above must end in ";" (not even spaces after) and the J must start
// on the very first columns.
```

Other sections in the same file would be called JS002, and so on. Inside each "here-document" section, if you want to embed a php variable write it like `{$variable}`, and if you have a `$` sign otherwise, escape it with a backslash, `\$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script>
alert("hhh");
</script>';
? >
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer means and how it slots in with OP's code.

Comment: You cannot call PHP code within JavaScript, as JavaScript is client side and PHP is server side.

Comment: Vishal, the purpose is to explain your answer for everyone to understand it properly.  So, please edit your answer and add this comment there.  Just pretend that the audience knows less than you.  Then I will upvote it.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32413900)